# Metals VS Code connection to build server failing

Tags: scala, scala-metals

I've set up a Scala project with the metals extension and when importing the the build.sbt, this fails and im provided with the following error message and this metals.log
`Failed to connect with build server, no functionality will work. See logs for more details.`

[metals.log](https://jpst.it/2SrN7)
Due to there only being 30.000 chars allowed and the log being 40.000+ I've shared it via a link.
The short version would be this:

```
2022.06.11 15:33:58 INFO  tracing is disabled for protocol LSP, to enable tracing of incoming and outgoing JSON messages create an empty file at c:\Users\USER\Documents\WORKSPACE\.metals\lsp.trace.json or C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\scalameta\metals\cache\lsp.trace.json
2022.06.11 15:34:03 INFO  logging to file C:\Users\USER\Documents\WORKSPACE\.metals\metals.log
2022.06.11 15:34:03 INFO  Started: Metals version 0.11.6 in workspace 'C:\Users\USER\Documents\WORKSPACE' for client Visual Studio Code 1.68.0.
2022.06.11 15:34:10 INFO  time: initialize in 7.57s
2022.06.11 15:34:13 WARN  Flyway upgrade recommended: H2 2.1.212 is newer than this version of Flyway and support has not been tested. The latest supported version of H2 is 2.1.210.
2022.06.11 15:34:14 WARN  Build server is not auto-connectable.
2022.06.11 15:34:22 WARN  no build target for: C:\Users\USER\Documents\WORKSPACE\src\main\scala\ex08\Run.scala
2022.06.11 15:34:28 INFO  running 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.14\bin\java -Djline.terminal=jline.UnsupportedTerminal -Dsbt.log.noformat=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\metals10676834532196762278\sbt-launch.jar -Dbloop.export-jar-classifiers=sources bloopInstall'
2022.06.11 15:34:38 INFO  no build target found for C:\Users\USER\Documents\WORKSPACE\src\main\scala\ex08\Run.scala. Using presentation compiler with project's scala-library version: 3.1.2
2022.06.11 15:34:46 INFO  [info] welcome to sbt 1.6.2 (Oracle Corporation Java 11.0.14)
2022.06.11 15:34:51 INFO  [info] loading settings for project exercises-build-build-build from metals.sbt ...
2022.06.11 15:34:52 INFO  time: code lens generation in 23s
2022.06.11 15:34:52 INFO  time: code lens generation in 24s
2022.06.11 15:34:52 INFO  time: code lens generation in 28s
2022.06.11 15:34:52 INFO  time: code lens generation in 28s
2022.06.11 15:34:54 INFO  [info] loading project definition from C:\Users\USER\Documents\WORKSPACE\project\project\project
2022.06.11 15:34:57 INFO  [info] loading settings for project exercises-build-build from metals.sbt ...
2022.06.11 15:34:57 INFO  [info] loading project definition from C:\Users\USER\Documents\WORKSPACE\project\project
2022.06.11 15:35:10 INFO  [success] Generated .bloop\exercises-build-build.json
2022.06.11 15:35:10 INFO  [success] Total time: 11 s, completed 11.06.2022, 15:35:10
2022.06.11 15:35:11 INFO  [info] loading settings for project exercises-build from metals.sbt ...
2022.06.11 15:35:11 INFO  [info] loading project definition from C:\Users\USER\Documents\WORKSPACE\project
2022.06.11 15:35:16 INFO  [success] Generated .bloop\exercises-build.json
2022.06.11 15:35:16 INFO  [success] Total time: 5 s, completed 11.06.2022, 15:35:16
2022.06.11 15:35:16 INFO  [info] loading settings for project root from build.sbt ...
2022.06.11 15:35:17 INFO  [info] set current project to exercises (in build file:/C:/Users/USER/Documents/WORKSPACE/)
2022.06.11 15:35:19 INFO  [success] Generated .bloop\root.json
2022.06.11 15:35:19 INFO  [success] Generated .bloop\root-test.json
2022.06.11 15:35:19 INFO  [success] Total time: 1 s, completed 11.06.2022, 15:35:19
2022.06.11 15:35:20 INFO  time: ran 'sbt bloopInstall' in 51s
2022.06.11 15:35:20 INFO  Attempting to connect to the build server...
2022.06.11 15:35:36 ERROR Starting the bsp launcher for bloop...
2022.06.11 15:35:36 ERROR Opening a bsp server connection with 'bsp --protocol tcp --port 24387'...
2022.06.11 15:35:36 ERROR Waiting for the bsp connection to come up...
2022.06.11 15:35:36 ERROR Waiting for the bsp connection to come up...
2022.06.11 15:35:36 ERROR Waiting for the bsp connection to come up...
2022.06.11 15:35:36 ERROR Waiting for the bsp connection to come up...
2022.06.11 15:35:36 ERROR Waiting for the bsp connection to come up...
2022.06.11 15:35:36 ERROR Waiting for the bsp connection to come up...
2022.06.11 15:35:36 ERROR error: The command bsp --protocol tcp --port 24387 returned with an error
2022.06.11 15:35:36 ERROR > No server running at 127.0.0.1:8212, let's fire one...
2022.06.11 15:35:36 ERROR > Resolving ch.epfl.scala:bloop-frontend_2.12:1.5.0-18-003e6c7b...
2022.06.11 15:35:36 ERROR > Attempting a connection to the server...
2022.06.11 15:35:36 ERROR > Starting bloop server at 127.0.0.1:8212...
2022.06.11 15:35:36 ERROR > java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.12\bin\java" (in directory "c:\Users\USER\Documents\WORKSPACE"): CreateProcess error=2, Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden
2022.06.11 15:35:36 ERROR >     at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1128)
2022.06.11 15:35:36 ERROR >     at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1071)
2022.06.11 15:35:36 ERROR >     at bloop.bloopgun.BloopgunCli.sysproc$1(Bloopgun.scala:487)
2022.06.11 15:35:36 ERROR >     at bloop.bloopgun.BloopgunCli.sysprocWithJava$1(Bloopgun.scala:502)
2022.06.11 15:35:36 ERROR >     at bloop.bloopgun.BloopgunCli.startServer(Bloopgun.scala:546)
2022.06.11 15:35:36 ERROR >     at bloop.bloopgun.BloopgunCli$FireInBackground$.$anonfun$fire$1(Bloopgun.scala:314)
2022.06.11 15:35:36 ERROR >     at bloop.bloopgun.core.Shell$$anon$2.run(Shell.scala:152)
2022.06.11 15:35:36 ERROR > Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden
2022.06.11 15:35:36 ERROR >     at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
2022.06.11 15:35:36 ERROR >     at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:487)
2022.06.11 15:35:36 ERROR >     at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:154)
2022.06.11 15:35:36 ERROR >     at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1107)
2022.06.11 15:35:36 ERROR >     ... 6 more
2022.06.11 15:35:36 ERROR > Starting bloop server at 127.0.0.1:8212...
2022.06.11 15:35:36 ERROR > java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.12\bin\java" (in directory "c:\Users\USER\Documents\WORKSPACE"): CreateProcess error=2, Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden
2022.06.11 15:35:36 ERROR >     at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1128)
2022.06.11 15:35:36 ERROR >     at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1071)
2022.06.11 15:35:36 ERROR >     at bloop.bloopgun.BloopgunCli.sysproc$1(Bloopgun.scala:487)
2022.06.11 15:35:36 ERROR >     at bloop.bloopgun.BloopgunCli.sysprocWithJava$1(Bloopgun.scala:502)
2022.06.11 15:35:36 ERROR >     at bloop.bloopgun.BloopgunCli.startServer(Bloopgun.scala:562)
2022.06.11 15:35:36 ERROR >     at bloop.bloopgun.BloopgunCli$FireInBackground$.$anonfun$fire$1(Bloopgun.scala:314)
2022.06.11 15:35:36 ERROR >     at bloop.bloopgun.core.Shell$$anon$2.run(Shell.scala:152)
2022.06.11 15:35:36 ERROR > Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden
2022.06.11 15:35:36 ERROR >     at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
2022.06.11 15:35:36 ERROR >     at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:487)
2022.06.11 15:35:36 ERROR >     at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:154)
2022.06.11 15:35:36 ERROR >     at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1107)
2022.06.11 15:35:36 ERROR >     ... 6 more

[MISSING BLOCK, SEE LINK]

2022.06.11 15:35:36 ERROR > Error: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.12\bin\java" (in directory "c:\Users\USER\Documents\WORKSPACE"): CreateProcess error=2, Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden'
2022.06.11 15:35:36 ERROR > Attempt connection a last time before giving up...
2022.06.11 15:35:36 ERROR > Attempting a connection to the server...
2022.06.11 15:35:36 ERROR > error: Server could not be started at None:Some(8212)! Giving up...
2022.06.11 15:35:36 ERROR error: The launcher failed to establish a bsp connection, aborting...
2022.06.11 15:35:36 ERROR Failed to connect with build server, no functionality will work.
java.lang.RuntimeException: The server did not start, got FailedToOpenBspConnection
    at bloop.launcher.LauncherMain.failPromise$1(Launcher.scala:92)
    at bloop.launcher.LauncherMain.runLauncher(Launcher.scala:119)
    at scala.meta.internal.metals.BloopServers$$anon$2.run(BloopServers.scala:434)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

(There are some bits of German which hopefully aren't important to understand)

Hopefully someone knows why this happens and how to fix it.

Comment: Actually, your assumption was completely incorrect. The German was actually very important, and thankfully I speak a little. You don't have your Java path setup correctly for metals. Make sure that is actually the correct path.

Comment: @Aliics Oh okay, currently I've set Metlas: Java Home to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.14, which is what I've read I have to do, but it doesn't work.
Is this the wrong path?